# view SetAlpha not working in android version 5 - lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I have set alpha to my relative layout in following way,

```
holder.layoutMenuItem.getBackground().setAlpha(alpha*255/100);
```

It is working perfect in all versions except verion 5 - lollipop. 
Any one is having solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#**238974"));
```

Where `*` is your Alpha level.

In my case `view.setAlpha((float)0.3);` worked perfectly too.

Comment: I want to set alpha to not my view but to the background i set to that view. So setting backgroundcolor to that view worked for me. Thanks a lot..